# If you had a good enough power source, could a gyroscope be used for flying/levitation

Tags: levitation

I don't know anything about physics, this is a shower thought i need answered for inner peace.

Also, if the answer is yes, HOW good would the power source need to be, let's say electricity wise, to levitate let's say a 10 tonne plane with a gyroscope.

If this is not possible, then (again assuming we could slap a working fusion drive into a plane) could we get a plane out of orbit using just electricity.

Answer (score 2):

The weird behavior of a gyroscope in many respects is coming from the attempts of the latter to preserve its angular momentum (both magnitude and direction). Now if you have a body with an angular momentum $\vec{L}$, the latter is not going to change if you move the whole body without rotating it ("parallel shift"). Therefore the presence (or the lack) of $\vec{L}$ is not going to affect the way the center of mass of the body is going to fall down. So the answer is no.

The above was just to put some gyroscope discussion in. Otherwise, already Newton's second law, in application to the center of mass motion, is telling you that the acceleration of the center of mass only depends on the force of gravity.